# NULL window handler in function 'cvSetMouseCallback'

Tags: python, opencv, ipython

I am working on a project where i have to use Mouse as a paintbrush. I have used `cv2.setMouseCallback()` function but it returned the following error.
here is the part of my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# mouse callback function
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),100,(255,0,0),-1)

# Create a black image, a window and bind the function to window
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

when I run this It returned me the following error:
error                                     Traceback

```
(most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-640e54baca5f> in <module>
     10 img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
     11 cv2.namedWindow('image')
---> 12 cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)
     13 
     14 while(1):

error: OpenCV(4.3.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp:717: error: (-27:Null pointer) NULL window handler in function 'cvSetMouseCallback'
```

My python version - 3.8
Operating System - ubuntu 20

Comment: code works for me on Python 3.7 / Linux MInt 19.2 (based on Ubuntu 18). Used normally `python script.py` without `ipython`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is resolved I removed the previously installed OpenCV

(which is installed using pip `pip install opencv-python`) and reinstalled it using

`sudo apt install libopencv-dev python3-opencv`

Comment: it worked for me, but i want to know why this happen? whats wrong with `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python` and `pip3 install opencv-python`.

Answer (score 1):

add the same namedWindow worked for me

```
cv2.namedWindow("video")
cv2.imshow("video", image)
cv2.setMouseCallback("video", drawLine)
```

Answer (score -1):

for me, also worked with the pip3 installations.
Just made a fresh virtual env, and installed opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python.