# python cv2: detecting window closed

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface

I needed to reactivat some old code which includes
`while(cv.getWindowProperty(msg, 1)) >= 0):` to check when a window was closed. I already downgraded my python to 3.8 and installed all packages with the version from back then, but am still getting some error

`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:837: error: (-27:Null pointer) NULL window: 'Window name' in function 'cvGetPropWindowAutoSize_W32'`

and can't figure out why, as I can't debug into `getWindowProperty()`.
Did anybody already come across this mistake?

Comment: What's the value of `msg` in this statement?

Comment: It is just the name of the window.

Comment: A search for your error shows a whole bunch of other SO posts already, so, yeah: other people already ran into this. Remember to [search](/help/how-to-ask) and check all the results for whether they apply. If not: mention those posts and _how_ they didn't solve the problem in your post. For example, does this answer your question? [NULL window handler in function 'cvSetMouseCallback'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62801244/null-window-handler-in-function-cvsetmousecallback)

Comment: catch the exception? write a function to call this getter, return false from exception handling, true otherwise -- @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the point is to detect when a window no longer exists. the lookup is supposed to come back NULL. OP appears to be hesitant to catch the exception.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: yes you a right, I should have explained a bit more. I had already been searching but the solution you linked unfortunately didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific property for this: `WND_PROP_VISIBLE`. This has existed since late 2016 and was introduced by https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/7561

```
if cv.getWindowProperty("foo", cv.WND_PROP_VISIBLE):
    print("it's there")
else:
    print("it's not there")
```

---

Alternatively, query any other property, then catch the exception and react to it.

```
import cv2 as cv # recommended way to import OpenCV

def does_the_window_exist(winname):
    try:
        cv.getWindowProperty(winname, cv.WND_PROP_AUTOSIZE) # any property
        return True # that worked, so it exists
    except cv.error as e:
        if e.code == -27: # (-27:Null pointer) lookup didn't find such a window
            return False
        else:
            raise # some unanticipated error

print(does_the_window_exist("foo")) # => False
```

Comment: Thank you, cv.WND_PROP_VISIBLE works perfectly fine. :)